# find the $a_{111}$ if $a_{n+11}=a_{n+5}+2a_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

Let sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ such $$a_{1}=a_{2}=\cdots=a_{10}=0,a_{11}=2$$,such
$$a_{n+11}=a_{n+5}+2a_{n}$$

Find the $a_{111}$

I want show this sequence is Periodic series。following is some try

$$a_{n+11}=a_{n+5}+2a_{n}$$
$$a_{n+17}=a_{n+11}+2a_{n+6}=a_{n+5}+2a_{n}+2a_{n+6}$$

Comment: Why do you believe that the sequence is periodic?

Comment: do you mean $a_{1,11}$ or $a_{11,1}$ or $a_{1,1,1}$ ?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial for the recursion is $\lambda^{11}-\lambda^5-2$, which doesn't have terribly nice roots.

Comment: If the question is indeed from an exam then solving the relation is out of the question, the way is probably to decompose $n+11=111$ using what you know about $n+5,n$ repeatedly

Comment: Missed: a sign.

Answer (score 6):

We easily see that the generating function of this sequence is
$$
A(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kx^k=\frac{2x^{11}}{1-x^6-2x^{11}}.
$$
By the sum formula of a geometric series $1/(1-q)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty q^k$ at $q=x^6+2x^{11}$ we arrive at the following identity of formal power series
$$
A(x)=2x^{11}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(x^6+2x^{11})^k.
$$
By the binomial formula the $k$th term contributes terms like $\binom{a+b}{a}x^{6a}(2^bx^{11b})$ where $a+b=k$. This term has degree $6a+11b$, and we are only interested in terms of degree $100$.

The parameters $a$ and $b$ are non-negative integers. It is relatively easy to figure out that the only solutions of $$6a+11b=100\qquad(*)$$ are $(a,b)=(2,8)$ and $(a,b)=(13,2)$. A good way is to observe that $(*)$ implies the congruence $6a\equiv100\equiv1\pmod{11}$, whence $a\equiv2\pmod{11}$.

Hence
$$
a_{111}=\binom{10}22^9+\binom{15}22^3=23880.
$$

---

This method may be useful whenever we have a suitably sparse recurrence relation. I don't recall having seen a general description of this though (but my recollection is not what it once was). Its usefulness is somewhat limited, because with higher indices the number of terms begins to grow. The actual problem may have been carefully drafted not to make this approach too arduous. The index $111$ was in a range where the number of terms was quite manageable.

Comment: More precisely, we want the feedback polynomial to be a trinomial, and the numerator of the generating function also to have only few terms.

Answer (score 4):

I just put it in a spreadsheet.  The sequence is not periodic.  I find $a_{111}=23880$ but don't see a neat way to get that.

Added:  if I had to do it by hand I would just follow the recurrence backwards
$$a_{111}=a_{105}+2a_{100}\\=a_{99}+4a_{94}+4a_{89}\\
=a_{93}+6a_{88}+12a_{83}+8a_{78}$$
It will take about $18$ such lines.  After about $10$ lines terms will disappear off the end because of the known $0$ values.  It is a fair amount of work this way.

Comment: But this problem is from exam problem,so I think there exsit a solution by hand

Comment: Thanks,then How to find the $a_{96},a_{90},\cdots$ and so on

Comment: You just plug into the recurrence.  You can write it as $a_n=a_{n-6}+2a_{n-11}$.  That is how I got each of the equalities in my addition.  I discovered an error in my computation, which is easy to make.  I did the first four of twenty lines.  They get longer by one term each time until the tenth one.

Comment: @Holo:  you are correct.  That rippled through.  Thanks